# Spring Batch: how to avoid IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm developing a batch application using Spring Batch with Java 11.
This is my reader() method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<MyClass> reader() {
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper beanWrapperMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MyClass>();
    beanWrapperMapper.setTargetType(MyClass.class);

    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MyClass>()
            .name("MyClassReader")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(inputFolder.concat(File.separator).concat("my-input-file.csv")))
            .delimited()
            .names("field1", "field2")
            .fieldSetMapper(beanWrapperMapper)
            .build();
}
```

I did several tests and when the file `my-input-file.csv` is there, the batch works fine. However, I would like to get the following behavior: if the file `my-input-file.csv` is missing, I still want something written to the output file and **no errors be raised**.
Right now, if I run the batch but the file is not in the folder, this error comes up:

```
IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): path [C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\src\\test\\resources\\my-input-file.csv]
```

I am aware that the error is because the file could not be found. But I really would like to handle this case to generate a different output file (and I don't want the batch process to fail).

How can this be done?

Comment: Check if the file exists before creating/returning the FlatFileItemReader and return something else instead?

Answer (score 1):

1. set the **strict** property to **false** so that input resource exceptions would not happen.
2. check the readCount after the batch job is completed. if readCount == 0, means no data, and you handle your logic here.

example for your case (implementing the JobExecutionListener):

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    StepExecution[] stepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().toArray(new StepExecution[]{});
    StepExecution stepExecution = stepExecutions[0];
    long readCount = stepExecution.getReadCount();
    if (readCount == 0) {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a common pattern, which is documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#handlingStepCompletionWhenNoInputIsFound.